# Angular 5 - Using value from a service in createServerRenderer

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-universal, asp-net-core-spa-services

I am using .Net Core Angular CLI based template (https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1288#issuecomment-346003334).

For server side rendering this template generates below **main.server** file.

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { createServerRenderer } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.module.server';

enableProdMode();

export default createServerRenderer(params => {

  const { AppServerModule, AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = (module as any).exports;

  const options = {
    document: params.data.originalHtml,
    url: params.url,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
      { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl }
    ]
  };

  const renderPromise = AppServerModuleNgFactory
    ? /* AoT */ renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, options)
    : /* dev */ renderModule(AppServerModule, options);

  return renderPromise.then(html => ({ html }));
});
```

Now, I also need to return the Http Status Code for example 404 for page not found.

For this I have created below **HttpStatusCodeService**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HttpStatusCodeService {

  private statusCode: number;

  constructor() {
    this.statusCode = 200;
  }

  public setStatusCode(statusCode: number) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
  }

  public getStatusCode(): number {
    return this.statusCode;
  }
}
```

and added it in providers of AppModule.

Now, I am not sure how to access the value of the status code from **HttpStatusCodeService** and use it in **main.server** file.

I tried modifying the **main.server** file to following

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { renderModule, renderModuleFactory } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { provideModuleMap } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';
import { createServerRenderer } from 'aspnet-prerendering';
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.module.server';

import { HttpStatusCodeService } from './app/shared/services/http-status-code.service';


enableProdMode();

export default createServerRenderer(params => {

  const { AppServerModule, AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = (module as any).exports;

  const options = {
    document: params.data.originalHtml,
    url: params.url,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
      { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl }
    ]
  };

  const renderPromise = AppServerModuleNgFactory
    ? /* AoT */ renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, options)
    : /* dev */ renderModule(AppServerModule, options);

  return renderPromise.then(html => {
    return { html: html, statusCode: httpStatusCodeService.getStatusCode()};
  });
});
```

But in order to make the above code work we need an instance of the **httpStatusCodeService**, I dont know how to access it in **createServerRenderer**.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: It's probably not exactly what you want, but I'm using nodeJs and what I did was injecting a response object into the httpStatusCodeService (using extraProviders like what you have), modify that object in the httpStatusCodeService to set the correct http code, and then use that object's value after rendering.

Answer (score 0):

useValue to the rescue:

```
export default createServerRenderer(params => {

const singleton = new SomeClass();

  const { AppServerModule, AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP } = (module as any).exports;

  const options = {
    document: params.data.originalHtml,
    url: params.url,
    extraProviders: [
      provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP),
      { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: params.baseUrl },
      { provide: 'BASE_URL', useValue: params.origin + params.baseUrl },
       { provide: SomeClass, useValue: singleton}
    ]
  };

  const renderPromise = AppServerModuleNgFactory
    ? /* AoT */ renderModuleFactory(AppServerModuleNgFactory, options)
    : /* dev */ renderModule(AppServerModule, options);

  return renderPromise.then(html => {

    return { html: html, statusCode: singleton.getStatusCode()};
  });
});
```